# Strip Bad Characters from an HTML PHP Contact Form

Tags: php, html, forms

New to PHP, but making new progress. I have a contact form that will send an email after it has been submitted by the user. Now I want to make this form better, by stripping out bad characters, or anything that could potentially wreck an email. The email will be read by me, so I could technically browse through all the spam, but I don't want to. I want a clean email coming in for documentation purposes.

I am using the $_POST array, here is the HTML for the contact form:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="contact.php">

<p class="name">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  <label for="name">Name</label>
</p>

<p class="email">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  <label for="email">E-mail</label>
</p>

<p class="web">
  <input type="text" name="web" id="web" />
  <label for="web">Website</label>
</p>

<p class="telephone">
  <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" />
  <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
</p>

<p class="question">Preferred Contact Method</p>
  <p id="preferred_question">
    <input type="radio" name="contact_option" class="telephone_opt" value="Telephone" />
    <label for="telephone_opt">Telephone</label><br />

    <input type="radio" name="contact_option" class="email_opt" value="Email" />
    <label for="email_opt">Email</label></p>

<p class="question">Describe what you need..</p>
  <p class="text">
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
</p>

<p class="submit">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</p>

</form>
```

Here is my contact.php (form action file)

```
<?php
$msg = "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "<br />";
$msg .= "Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "<br />";
$msg .= "Website: " . $_POST['web'] . "<br />";
$msg .= "Telephone: " . $_POST['telephone'] . "<br />";
$msg .= "Preferred Contact Method: " . $_POST['contact_option'] . "<br />";
$msg .= "Customer Needs: " . $_POST['text'];

$recipient = "support@mysite.com";
$subject = "Contact Has Been Made..";
$mailheaders = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$mailheaders .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$mailheaders .= "From: <support@mysite.com>" . "\r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: what is a " bad character" ? (them shady kids hanging out on the corner are real bad characters)

Comment: what characters can "wreck" an email, do you mean the email address or the email message? Or do you mean a filter, like a spam filter?

Comment: check out the "addslashes" function, might do what you want - otherwise anyone entering quotes could bust your code.  Also you may want to check htmlentities if you're getting this as an html email!

Comment: I guess saying "bad character" was vague. I do want a spam filter. I also don't want to see html tags, quotes, etc in fields, such as name, telephone, etc. I also don't want text, in the telephone field, just numeric items and minus or plus symbol or brackets for intl numbers. For website, I want it to be valid url, not something like mywebsite.()com. You know basic filtering/sanitizing of this data..

Comment: then you should validate each field separately according to your requirements

Comment: Check my answer...filter_input sainitize your input (in case of an email for example). You should validate all datas before sending it using this method + several other RegExp when necessary (phone number, postal code, wtv)

Answer (score 1):

Try this function as a good starting point:

```
function cleanInput($input) {
    // Pass the $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST array
    $output = array();

    foreach ($input as $key=>$value) {
        $o = $value;

        // Make sure it's within the max length
        $o = substr($o,0,256);

        // Tidy up line breaks
        $o = preg_replace('/\n{2,}/', "\n\n", $o);
        $o = nl2br($o,FALSE);

        // Strip any odd characters
        $o = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\. -\!\?\(\)\<\>\@]/', "", $o);

        // Put the data back in the array
        $output[$key] = $o;
    }

    // Return the array
    return $output;
}
```

Usage: `$post = cleanInput($_POST);`

Then replace the `$_POST`s with `$post`: `$_POST['name']` would become `$post['name']`.

Comment: Updated answer - I just pasted this in from something I'd written. Should've proofread it. Now corrected.

Comment: still bad, ascii only?

Comment: Feel free to post a better answer rather than criticising everyone else.

Comment: oh it would destroy the posted email address by removeing the @ as well

Comment: Still no solution from you I see.

Comment: there is no single magic solution, as i pointed out already, each field requires it's own validation. you want to validate all of post at once, will never work

Comment: The OP asks for "basic filtering/sanitizing of this data" and to "Strip Bad Characters from an HTML PHP Contact Form" the above function does that. The question needs changing if they want form validation.

Comment: lets not argue, your code is bad no mater what it is for, you cant accept that, so be it - peace out.

Comment: Again, feel free to post a better solution. You've offered lots of criticism on other answers without actually posting an answer to address the question. Basically you're comment trolling.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might wanna think about filtering theses datas with the filter_input function ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php ). A little security update ;)
You can striptags ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php ) allowing only the wanted TAGS, you  can also think about addslahes() or stripslashes() to remove or add "".  Finally, you might want to encode the text properly (utf-8?) in order to see all special characters using htmlentities ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php ). I myself use htmlentities (utf-8) and strip_tags() to send custom emails!
Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, check out this simple little tutorial:

http://www.stemkoski.com/php-remove-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string/

Modify this to replace any character you want. Honestly, to the best of my ability this answers what I think you're asking. But if not, just do a google search, this question is pretty basic.

If you meant you want field validation, (so you'll only accept specifically formatted data), just do a quick search on it and you'll find great resources. Heres a whole tutorial that may be just what you need:
http://buildinternet.com/2008/12/how-to-validate-a-form-complete-with-error-messages-using-php-part-1/

These two solutions probably gotcha covered :)

Comment: non-ascii does not = bad, more than half the world have non-ascii characters in their name

Comment: agreed, this just shows how to do a "replace", I trust he'll know how to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like besides a blanket filter for all values, you're looking for input validation. Here's a function for email validation. This uses regular expressions. I'm not going to write the code for all your requirements, but you can use this to start from.

```
function  checkEmail($email) {
    if (!preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/' , $email)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How about the reason for the downvote? I merely gave him a sample for using regular expressions.

Comment: Im not the one that downvoted you, I would like to see who downvoted me as well

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function:

```
  function sanitize($data){
        $data= htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($data)));
  $search = array('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',  // Strip out javascript
                   '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            // Strip out HTML tags
                   '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
                   '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments including CDATA
    ); 
   $data = preg_replace($search, '', $data); 
        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took in alot of what you all told me and put something together from all of your answers.

Here is what I went with:

```
<?php
// Sanitize the data so its nice and clean..
function sanitize($data) {
$data = strip_tags(trim($data));
$search = array('/[^A-Za-z0-9\. -\!\?\(\)\<\>\@]/');
$data = preg_replace($search, '', $data);
return $data;
}

$msg = "Name: " . sanitize($_POST['name']) . "<br />";
$msg .= "Email: " . sanitize($_POST['email']) . "<br />";
$msg .= "Website: " . sanitize($_POST['web']) . "<br />";
$msg .= "Telephone: " . sanitize($_POST['telephone']) . "<br />";
$msg .= "Preferred Contact Method: " . sanitize($_POST['contact_option']) . "<br />";
$msg .= "Customer Needs: " . sanitize($_POST['text']);

$recipient = "support@mywebsite.com";
$subject = "Contact Has Been Made..";
$mailheaders = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$mailheaders .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$mailheaders .= "From: <support@mywebsite.com>" . "\r\n";

// Mail the message..
mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);
echo "Thank you for your email!<br/><br/>";
?>
```